# Standard Position of a Quaternion?

Tags: c++, math, unity-game-engine, quaternions

In 2D, the standard position of a vector is down the positive X axis. Is there an equivalent position for quaternions?

Comment: I've never heard of a "standard position" for a vector. Where did you get that from?

Comment: there's no standard position for a vector.

Comment: I meant standard position angle. The point is, atan2() returns 0 degrees for the angle of a vector pointing down the positive x axis. This is useful because any art(arrows, ect) that will be imported into a game can be made to match up with vectors in game by pointing it in the positive X direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "standard position of a vector." In 2D or 3D.

There is of course a general mathematical convention that the X,Y direction of an angle is (cos(angle), sin(angle)). Which means that if the angle is 0, then the vector points down the positive X axis. But that's far from a "standard position of a vector."

While quaternions can seem like a 3D angle in some math operations, they are *not* angles. Quaternions (in terms of graphics) represent the orientation of a space, relative to another space.

Comment: as noted in the comment above, the purpose of this question is to import any directional or arrow-like art into the game in a certain pose so that it will match up with any vector in game

Comment: @Nick: Quaternions are not angles. You cannot turn a direction into a quaternion without having some reference frame. Indeed, you cannot turn a 2D vector into an angle without a reference frame; `atan2` does it by _defining_ a frame of reference.

Comment: so there is not such function as this:  

Quaternion q = RotateTo(vector3); object.RotateBy(q);
  
where I can point my object in a certain direction in the editor to have it match up with that vector?

Comment: @Nick: You could create such a function by doing what `atan2` does: defining a frame of reference. Defining an initial coordinate system which all quaternions used for this purpose are relative to. Your `RotateTo` function would create orientation changes relative to this coordinate system.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. I think I found what I need...This function can take any input direction I want : 
http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion.SetFromToRotation.html. Thanks